# Format ResultSet to specific DecimalFormat in Univocity Parser

Tags: java, univocity

In my project I've been using `Univocity-parsers` to convert SQL queries into CSV files.
It used to first map the queries to `Java Beans` and then used `CsvRoutines` to write the CSV.

```
public static class Bean {
    @Parsed(field = "double_value")
    public Double doubleValue;

    public Bean(Double doubleValue) {
        this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
    }
}

@Test
public void writeToCsv() {
    List<Bean> beans = List.of(new Bean(10.0), new Bean(50.5), new Bean(12.0));
    CsvRoutines csvRoutines = new CsvRoutines();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    csvRoutines.writeAll(beans, Bean.class, stringWriter);
    System.out.println(stringWriter);
}
```

This gives the following result:

```
10.0
50.5
12.0
```

Now I'm refactoring for a more generic approach to dump the `ResultSet` directly into the `CsvRoutines`.
Similar to the example above, I made a small table in Postgres:

```
create table bean(
    double_value numeric
);
insert into bean values (10), (50.5), (12);

@Test
public void writeToCsv() throws SQLException {
    Connection c = createJdbcConnection();
    PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement("select double_value from bean");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    CsvRoutines csvRoutines = createCsvRoutines();
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    csvRoutines.write(rs, stringWriter);
    System.out.println(stringWriter);
}
```

Now, the result doesn't always include the decimal numbers.

```
10
50.5
12
```

I'd like it to produce the exact same output as in the initial version for compatibility reasons.
I've tried configuring a custom `ObjectRowWriterProcessor`, but it doesn't seem to format it correctly.

```
private CsvRoutines createCsvRoutines() {
    CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();
    ObjectRowWriterProcessor rowProcessor = new ObjectRowWriterProcessor();
    rowProcessor.convertType(Double.class, Conversions.formatToNumber("0.0"));
    writerSettings.setRowWriterProcessor(rowProcessor);
    return new CsvRoutines(writerSettings);
}
```

How can I configure the `CsvRoutines` to always write in the `0.0` format like initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `ObjectRowWriterProcessor` approach works fine, but the type at runtime is `BigDecimal` instead of a `Double`.

So changing the following line does produce the desired result:

```
rowProcessor.convertType(BigDecimal.class, Conversions.formatToNumber("0.0"));
```